# ng-inspector slows and crashes page. Where to look

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app where if I open the `ng-inspector` sidebar (which I really like to use) the page slows down to the point of not being usable and eventually crashes.

I assume it is something in my app that is doing this. I tried commenting out everything but the very topmost controller with no luck, still the same effect.

- What could cause this?
- Any suggestions on where to look?

At this point I am simply out of ideas.

Comment: A bug in ng-inspector perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

please check this link .[Injector token error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/itkn)
     And using the brackets solves this issue. It's only an issue in the latest Chrome. Firefox/Safari don't seem to be affected

Sample code:

```
  .directive('modalTransclude', [function () {
    return {
      // directive code
    };
  }])
```

and if above solution doesnt work try:

Then problem must be lying in ng-inspector v0.5.9 , i think most people have same problem . try updating that to latest version .